# C++ function overloading within classes

Tags: c++, class, oop, operator-overloading, overloading

I have declared a class Image with two operator() functions, one for read-only, the other for read-and-write access.

Here an extract:

```
class Image {
  //...
  public: 

  uint16_t operator()(int x, int y) const
  {
    return data_[x + y*width_];                  // read-only at pixle (x,y)
  }

  uint16_t & operator()(int x, int y)
  {
    return data_[x + y*width_];                 // read/write to pixle (x,y)
  }

 //... 
}
```

After this, I declared an object of Image in the main() function and wrote to it (which has to work because of the mentioned public Interface operator()), but several compilers only keep recognizing the first operator() function which has only permission to read.

Example of this:

```
if (count_alive_neighbors(image, i, j) == 3) {
   image(i, j) = 255; 
}
```

My thought was that maybe one could overcome this problem by declaring a pointer and by this changing the value. Code for this:

```
    uint16_t* f = &image(i, j);
    *f = 255;
```

On Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 this first worked tested alone outside the if-loop, but inside the just mentioned function it didn't. But it's not a compiler error, I've tested it with Clang, g++ and MinGW.

All are printing out an error message like this:

```
 error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
     uint16_t* f = &(image(i, j));
                      ^
```

To sum it up, the question is the following: how could one overcome this problem by not focusing on that pointer declarations, what can one do to tell the compiler which version of operator() it has to use? It doesn't recognize it on its own or maybe I'm not recognizing which settings/code one has to change to make the program work.

Thanks in advance.

edit: whole class definition and function

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>

class Image
{
    int width_;
    int height_;
    std::vector<uint16_t> data_;

    public:

    Image()
    : width_(0)
    , height_(0)
    {}

    Image(unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
    : width_(width)
    , height_(height)
    , data_(width*height, uint16_t())
    {}

    int width() const
    {
        return width_;
    }

    int height() const
    {
        return height_;
    }

    int size() const
    {
        return width_*height_;
    }

    void resize(unsigned int new_width, unsigned int new_height)
    {
        data_.resize(new_width*new_height, uint16_t());
        width_  = new_width;
        height_ = new_height;
    } 

    uint16_t operator()(int x, int y) const
    {
        return data_[x + y*width_];
    }

    uint16_t & operator()(int x, int y)
    {
        return data_[x + y*width_];
    }

    uint16_t get_periodic(int x, int y) const
    {
        int xres = x % width_;
        int yres = y % height_;

        return data_[xres + yres*width_];
    }
};


int count_alive_neighbors(Image const & image, int x, int y) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
            if (image.get_periodic(x + i, y + j) == 255) {
                res += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (image.get_periodic(x, y) == 255) {
        res -= 1;
    }
}

Image conway_step(Image const & image) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= image.width(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= image.height(); j++) {
            if (count_alive_neighbors(image, i, j) == 2)
            {
            }

            if (count_alive_neighbors(image, i, j) == 3) {
                image(i, j) = 255;
            }

            if (count_alive_neighbors(image, i, j) < 2) {
               image(i, j) = 0;
            }

            if (count_alive_neighbors(image, i, j) > 3) {
                image(i, j) = 255;  
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    Image img(3, 3);              // declaring object
    img(3, 3) = 255;              /* !ATTENTION! this works, but inside       
                                     conway_steps it doesn't */

}
```

Comment: "but several compilers only keep recognizing the first operator() function which has only permission to read" - Post some compilable code that illustrates this problem/

Comment: if (count_alive_neighbors(image, i, j) == 3) {
            image(i, j) = 255; 
        }
if i use this code, it only recognizes the first read-only Operator.

Comment: Post a lot more code, and do it in the question.

Comment: @Niyu Can it be that you pass the object image to the function by const reference?:)

Comment: Looks like, @VladfromMoscow  : `Image conway_step(Image *****const****** & image)`

Comment: Now you can see the "full" code. Basically it's a simulation of Conway's game of life, if you don't want to go through the whole code.
@VladfromMoscow, can you explain what you mean or is there a chance of a misunderstanding now solved going through the code?

Comment: You pass a `const` reference into `conway_step` and then try to change it inside the function. Can't do that. It'll have to be passed in non `const`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I think I got the point. But our prof wants us to use this function definition and getting the job done by this, so it might be an impossible task within the given restrictions. That's why I tried to surpass this problem by working with pointers. But if you're only able to read, that's never going to work within the given function declaration by the prof.

Comment: `conway_step` is also missing a `return` statement this will result in undefined badness.

Comment: The prof may have a sneaky trick up his or her sleeve, you may be mis-interpretting an assignment requirement and the prof may have screwed up. The prof's probably the best person to ask at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Based on the comments] `conway_step` is supposed to make a copy of its argument, modify that copy, and return the copy. Your problem is that you don't make the copy and try to modify the original.

Answer (score -2):

Please change your function signature from

```
Image conway_step(Image const & image)
```

to

```
Image conway_step(Image & const image) //ill formed
```

or in a better way

```
Image conway_step(Image & image)
```

In first case, it is equivalent to `const Image & image`, so it calls the `const` qualified operator => `image(i, j)=255`; => `uint16_t=255` => `left operand must be l-value`  error

In second/third case, you declare a const reference to a non const object.

Comment: Incorrect. There's no such thing as a "const reference to a non-const object". Should just be `conway_step(Image& image)`.

Comment: I agree that `conway_step(Image& image)` will work fine too! The solution is to pass a non const object as parameter. But I totally disagree with your first affirmation. Did you try and check my proposal? (I did)

Comment: "[8.3.2] References" literally says "Cv-qualified references are ill-formed".

Comment: I agree with you that "Cv-qualified references are ill-formed" and may generate undefined behaviour depending on the used compiler. I've explicitely written this way in order to answer the issue and hilight the `const` qualifier order. The asker has to learn step by step.